# string padded with optional blank with max length

Tags: regex, padding, option-type

I have a problem building a regex. this is a sample of the text:

```
text 123 12345 abc 12    def 67 i 89 o 0    t 2
```

The numbers are sometimes padded with blanks to the max length (3).
e.g.:

- "1" can be "1" or "1  "
- "13" can be "13" or "13 "

My regex is at the moment this:

```
\b([\d](\s*)){1,3}\b
```

The results of this regex are the following: (`.` = blank for better visibility)

```
123.
12....
67.
89.
0....
2
```

But I need this: (. = blank for better visibility)

```
123
12.
67.
89.
0..
2
```

How can I tell the regex engine to count the blanks into the {1,3} option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
\b(?:\d[\d\s]{0,2})(?:(?<=\s)|\b)
```

This will also cover strings like `text 123 1 23 12345 123abc 12    def 67 i 89 o 0    t 2` and results in:

```
123
1.
23.
12.
67.
89.
0..
2
```

Comment: thanks that worked for me :)
can you help to change the regex where the blanks are before the numbers? i have tested this \b(?:(\s|\d)[\s\d]{0,2})(?:(?<=\d)|\b) but its not perfect because the word bounds are not working correctly :/

Comment: This should do it: `\b(?:[\d\s]{0,2}\d)(?:(?<=\s)|\b)`

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
\b(\d){1,3}\s*\b
```

This will also include whitespace (if available) after the selection.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
\b(?:\d[\d\s]{0,2})(?!\d)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2utnv)

the word boundary will not work at the end, because if the end of the match is a whitespace, there is no word boundary. Therefor I use a negative lookahead `(?!\d)` to ensure that there is no digit following.

But if you have a string like this "1 23". It will match only the "2" and the "23", but not the whitespace after the first "2".

Comment: Thank you for the hint to regexr. It's really cool for testing regex :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use the padded numbers somewhere else, break the problem apart into two; (simple) parsing the numbers, and (simple) formatting the numbers (including padding).

```
while ( $text =~ /\b(\d{1,3})\b/g ) {
  printf( "%-3d\n", $1 );
}
```

Alternatively:

```
@padded_numbers = map { sprintf( "%-3d", $_ ) } ( $text =~ /\b(\d{1,3})\b/g )
```